# Where does cups-pdf store its temporary files?

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, cups

I recently tried to save a rather large document using to a PDF using cups-pdf.  Something appears to have gone wrong and it went on to produce several GB worth of data somewhere on my hard drive, filling it almost to the brim until I finally managed to kill all processes involved for good (I hope).

What remains even after a reboot is the data created in the process of creating the PDF that I can't find. Since there is only a tiny bit of space left on my hard drive, I really want to delete it.

Where could that data be located?

I'm running Debian Jessie (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using `du` and sorting the result by size since quite a lot of data was created indeed. Apparently, cups-pdf keeps its temporary data in `/var/spool/cups-pdf/`, more specifically for my problem: `/var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL`. Emptying that directory freed quite a lot of space.